# Group policy on Open LDAP

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, ldap, openldap

Active directory on windows can give us many possibilities to manage out network such as **Group policy**.
In my company, we have Linux systems.
My question is:

> Is there any Linux based application or service that can handle the role of active directory GP on Linux that is not be depending on the distro.
>
> How About a Cross-platform management system that can include Windows,
>   Linux, and Mac.

Comment: „Is there X that does Y“ is a product recommendation question. The number of views this got is not relevant.

Comment: You asked "Is there any Linux based application that can handle X". This is clearly asking for a product. Had you asked "I want to do X with the product Y I found and run into issue Z", that question would have been on-topic.

Comment: If you question boils down to a product recommendation, then [SF] is not the site for you. For some cases, you might try [softwarerecs.se], but it's entirely possible your question is not a fit and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's Group Policy you're looking for, *per se*, but centralized management of a domain of (Linux) computers. In that case you are almost certainly looking for [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/), or its Red Hat Enterprise equivalent, [Identity Management](https://access.redhat.com/products/identity-management).

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand your question, if I'm not mistaken you need to manage linux machine through AD?

If that the case there is a tool called SSSD, which can retrieve AD GPO for linux. This tool is available in almost all linux distros. You can get more info about SSSD on RedHat site. See below link.

You can see the tutorial for ubuntu here:
[SSSD and Active Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html.en)

If you use opensuse you can use Yast to join AD.

If you need more info about GPO on linux you can access [Group Policy Object Access Control](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/sssd-gpo).